# ImportError: No module named 'telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3

Tags: python, git, bots, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to start making telegram bots with Python. But I have a boring error:

I was downloaded telegram-bot

```bash
$ git clone https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot
```

then

```bash
$ cd python-telegram-bot/

$ Python setup.py install

running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
..
..
..
Using g:\python\lib\site-packages\future-0.16.0-py3.5.egg
Finished processing dependencies for python-telegram-bot==9.0.0
```

but, when I want to import telegram, I see the following error:

```bash
ImportError: No module named 'telegram.vendor.ptb_urllib3.urllib3'
```

also:

```bash
$ python -i
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: $ python -i

Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Edit your question to show us the exact import statement you used, along with the full error message.

Answer (score 1):

The ptb_urllib3 is a submodule of the git repo and needs to be initalized with:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

Go manually to `..\telegram\vendor\ptb_urllib3` folder and check if its empty.

In case it is, manually download the [folder](http://%20[https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/urllib3/tree/06d04e451f6beb5562057bf793218c4e363d8bc0][1]) as a zip file and extract to the correct location.

If its not, make sure that your main file resides near the folder `telegram\`

Answer (score 0):

when the other solutions doesn't worked for me, i used pycharm to fix it.

just install PyCharm and create a new python file with that. and write:

```
import telegram
```

after writing code you'll see pycharm noticing you that telegram not installed yet and it will offer you installing telegram

that's it. just install telegram with pycharm

then you can run this code Without any error in pycharm terminal

Comment: It installs `telegram` instead of `python-telegram-bot` for me. Actually, it fails to install the former at all. Anyway, the solution proofs wrong.

Comment: i mentioned : when the other solutions doesn't worked for me, i used pycharm to fix it.